# Where to find the right Keras layer

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I have an idea for a deep learning layer, but I don't have the expertise to custom make it.  I'm wondering if anybody knows of a layer that already does what I'm thinking.

The Idea:

We think of the input as a function f(x) between a and b.  We could take the raw input, do a fft, then use the strongest frequencies.

We then have a function space G, and a parameterized path p(t) through G.  So g(p(t)) equals a function g(x).

We think of our output as a function h(t) = the integral of f(x)g(p(t))dx between a and b.

The gradients alter the variables within p(t), changing the path taken through the function space G. Different function spaces G and path spaces P could be tested.

In the end, the layer would be a mix between a fully connected layer and a convolutional layer.  In a fully connected layer, each output independently learns a function to multiply the input by, while in a convolutional layer, each output multiplies the input by the same learned function, just shifted.  In this layer, each output multiplies the input by a slightly different function than the outputs near it.  This layer can be represented purely algebraically, so I imagine better mathematicians than me could find a way to speed it up.  I also imagine you could make it multi-headed, like they do for attention in transformers.

I have looked through the [Keras layers](https://keras.io/api/layers/) but haven't found what I'm looking for.  Do I not understand one of the layers that do exist? Should I be looking somewhere else for layers? Is the idea flawed in some way?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Kindly provide complete code to reproduce from our end. So that I can understand to solve the question. Thank you.